# How to implement Django model audit trail? How do you access logged in user in models save() method?

Tags: django

I want to keep track of the user who creates and then updates all of a given model's records.  I have the "user" information in the logged in user's UserProfile (all users must be logged in to update these records).

Comment: This is really late however I've written a post exactly for that which may be useful for users that want to do model auditing in django: http://spapas.github.io/2015/01/21/django-model-auditing/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you're looking for [django-reversion](https://github.com/etianen/django-reversion), which allows you to keep track of all changes to a given model, including some meta data about the change (e.g. who made it).

Comment: Django-revision is more for tracking the status of a model as it evolves, doesn't seem to help with tracking the last user to modify the record.

Comment: Yes it does - see the "Version meta data" section of http://code.google.com/p/django-reversion/wiki/LowLevelAPI

Answer (score 1):

Django models do not (on purpose) have access to the `request` object. You must pass it to the model in a view.

Comment: why purposely not? I am running into a case right now where I feel I need to access the current user object inside a model.

Answer (score 1):

The quickest way to set the user field automatically for all changes made in the admin, would be by overriding the `save_model` method in your admin class (from the Django docs):

```
class ArticleAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        obj.user = request.user
        obj.save()
```

Otherwise, you can use something like django-revision mentioned by Dominic Rodger.

Answer (score 0):

I find django-simple-history very easy to use. Importantly, it has a customisation available for tracking reason of change which can be strategically used to get input from users for knowing the reason.